# Using global and local variables in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner to R programming, I was trying to create a for loop as mentioned below, when I run the code I get the correct output.

However when I only see mtcars$M the output is not the same as what I get when I run loop. Is there anything I missed while coding and how do we deal with global and local variable?

```
for (i in mtcars[,1]) {
  if(i >= 15){
   M <- print("the value is greter than 15")} else {
    M <-  print("the value is not greter than 15")
    mtcars$M <- M
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're error comes, because you assign the column M only, when the value is not greater than 15. So the whole column will be the same. You have to assign the value outside of the if-else condition and also specify in which row you want to save the value. If you just use `mtcars$M <- M` it will assign the vector M, to all the rows of that column.

```
for (i in seq_along(mtcars$mpg)) {
  if(mtcars$mpg[i] >= 15){
    M <- "the value is greter than 15"
  } else {
    M <-  "the value is not greter than 15"
  }
  print(M)
  mtcars$M[i] <- M
}

mtcars$M
```

Comment: Thank you  Boss 

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves your problem, could you please check the answer? It appears then as solved and gives the person who answered some reputation-points. :)